# Normal force not perpendicular to the surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, terminology, vectors, centripetal-force

In my class about mechanics i had to solve this problem, but it was never really explained. The solution is found beneath in a picture. In the solution they also calculate the angle of the normal force, but isn't the normal force always perpendicular to the contact surface in the contact point, so why isn't the normal force facing outwards and perpendicular to the tangent in that point. I've asked a lot of other students in my class, and none of them seem to understand this.

[image]

Comment: Usually the normal force is points perpendicular outwards from the surface like you said, but in this case in makes sense to define the normal force in a special way. Read the definition closely. (Maybe you think this definition doesn't make sense. You can think that, but as a good physicist you should still be able to solve the problem.)

Comment: I vote you are correct and the problem is either misguided or badly worded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Normal force" is simply bad notation. "Contact force" would be better. Usually, we don't distinguish, because the contact force is *almost* normal to the surface. But in the context of this detailed examination of the rotating Earth, it is confusing not to distinguish!

*Later Additions (incorporating comments)*

The contact force can be resolved into a component normal to the Earth (modelled as a sphere) and a small tangential (or frictional) component. If this component wasn't present, the body would be slipping round the Earth's surface, towards the equator!

I can't resist remarking that the 'textbook' treatment reproduced in the question is terribly long-winded. The results can be obtained in three or four lines by applying the cosine formula and the sine formula to a simple vector triangle.

Comment: **Contact force** is the vector sum of the frictional force and the normal force so even that is incorrect terminology.

Comment: @Harshit54 "Contact force is the vector sum of the frictional force and the normal force." Agreed, but that's why the terminology is right! The force $\mathbf{F_{N}}$  is the contact force and can indeed be split into normal and tangential components if required. You can call the tangential force the frictional component of the contact force if you wish. If this component wasn't present, the body would be slipping round the Earth's surface, towards the equator!

Comment: Oh, I just saw that they write the formula as $F_n=mg_{eff}$ so that takes the rotation into account. My apologies.

Comment: Agreed. The term "normal" means perpendicular or orthogonal to a surface. If a force isn't perpendicular to a surface, then it isn't a normal force, by definition.

Comment: Maybe the textbook author was trying to give an example of using $\textbf{i}$ and $\textbf j$ notation, but his/her solution is terribly long-winded. The whole thing can be done in 3 or 4 lines by applying sine and cosine formulae to a simple vector triangle.

Comment: Except the contact force may include friction, which isn't a normal force. I like the term constraint force and friction force which combined resolve to the contact force.

Comment: Instead of writing "Please also see my comment in the discussion below" you should incorporate the relevant comments to the answer. Comments are ephemeral by nature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i still have one small question, you said that the body would be slipping towards the equator, but why would that be? Does it have something to do with the fact that the rotational speed is greater at the equator or rather with the fact that the gravitational force is smaller at the equator, or something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

I think they just use incorrect terminology. What they call "normal force" is actually a vector sum of the normal force and the force of friction (the body would not rest in an arbitrary point of the surface of rotating Earth without friction).